# wxWidgets 2.9 learning resources

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, doc

I have a problem with wxWidgets 2.9. I just can't find any single tutorial/ebook/whatever about it. The VERY few that I found are for 2.8 and do not work with 2.9 (which is better and I want to use 2.9). The wxwidgets documentation is very poor (well not exactly poor, there are hundreds of classes documented but it lacks any good tutorial besides hello world app and the library itself is non-intuitive. It's nowhere near SFML 2's intuitive usage and extremely well done documentation (that you can easily learn SFML from there). It's so big a lib and even much smaller and less-used libs have 10x more learning resources. 2.9 is there for quite a some time, so I'm surprised that only 2.6/2.8 resources exist.

Could you share some 2.9 learning resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything you read about wxWidgets 2.8 applies to 2.9 too, just overview the chapter about the [changes since 2.8](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_changes_since28.html) in the manual.

The tutorials you're looking for are found in the `samples` subdirectory of wxWidgets distribution and there are almost a hundred of them. The best way to learn wxWidgets is by reading (and compiling and running) the samples.